# Puppeteer waitForSelector not working as expected

Tags: node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I've this simple code chunk:

```
const BUSINESS = 'lalala';
await page.waitForSelector('#searchboxinput').then(
    page.evaluate( (BUSINESS) => {
        document.querySelector('#searchboxinput').value = BUSINESS
    }, BUSINESS)
 ),
```

If I set wait for selector -> then, I would expect **then** to be executed **when the selector exists**, but I'm getting a **Cannot set property value of 'null'**.

So I uderstand that document.querySelector('#searchboxinput') == undefined while I suppose that it cannot be possible as it's executed when waitForSelector promise is finished...

is that a bug or I'm missing something?

**Edit:**

Imagine those two as separate chunks.

`await page.waitForSelector('#searchboxinput');`

I'd expect the code to continue after finding the given selector (`<whatever id="searchboxinput">`), because I already checked that this element exists at some point during the initial load (so we can avoid the unhappy path thinking on this question).

```
await page.waitForSelector('#searchboxinput');
// it should AWAIT for the selector to exists, then continue the execution
page.evaluate( ( someString ) => {
    // this querySelector should not return null due to the previous await
    document.querySelector('#searchboxinput').value = someString
}, someString)
```

Issue is that I got `Cannot set property value of 'null'`

I've solved this, this is not a question on "how to" but an intent to understand why this code didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly as your chunk is syntactically not complete and not reprducible. But what if you use the returned value of `page.waitForSelector()`? This seems working:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://example.org/');

  const BUSINESS = 'lalala';
  await page.waitForSelector('a').then((element) => {
    page.evaluate((element, BUSINESS) => {
      element.textContent = BUSINESS;
    }, element, BUSINESS);
  });
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```

Comment: yes it definitely does, but I can't understand why I cannot find a DOM element inside browser context after awaiting for the same selector unless you use the return value from waitForSelector. I mean, doesn't the DOM element must exists anyway at this time?

Comment: @JoelBonetR Can you provide a reproducible code?

Comment: @JoelBonetR According to the [documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) you can define in the options whether you want to have a selector be present in the DOM or not or only visually present.